# Applying css parent div

Tags: css, parent

I tried searching for option to apply css to parent div but failed to achieve it. I finally implemented the same with jquery. Do we have any option for the below jquery line to implement with css

```
 $('.description').parent().prev().closest('div').css('padding-top', '10px');
```

Comment: Nope, there is no parent CSS selector yet.

Comment: j08691 Yet :) I am hopeful it will be "<"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 1):

Currently no, there is not. This is similar to a previous thread -
[Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

However, you could just apply a class or id to your parent and select it in CSS using that newly set class/id.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your html looks a bit like this:

```
<div>
   <div class="description">
          ............
   </div>
</div>
```

Then the jQuery to target the parent of 'description' would be:

```
$('.description').parent().css('paddingTop', '10px');
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/EFmf8/
(changes colours instead of padding to better illustrate)

Pity there's no CSS selector for this . . .